# Prove that the polynomial $p(x)=\sqrt{2}x^3+4x^2+\frac{1}{7}x+10$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that the polynomial $p(x)=\sqrt{2}x^3+4x^2+\frac{1}{7}x+10$ is
continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and has a root in $\mathbb{R}$

Since $p(x)$ is polynomial by using algebraic properties of continuous the function is continue

how to find it has root in $\mathbb{R}$ I am also trying to find using mean value theorem but not get it

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг....im sorry I edited my question now its typing mistake

Comment: That is fine : the continuity argument still applies. You know that complex roots of a real polynomial come in conjugate pairs. Therefore, the number of (strictly) complex roots of any real polynomial must be even in number. Conclude that as the degree of your polynomial is odd, it must have a real root (Even easier than the quadratic case!)

Answer (score 1):

Let  $x_0>0$ be large enough such that $p(x_0)>0$ and $p(-x_0)<0$,
and Intermediate value theorem implies that there exists a real root for the polynomial $p(x).$

Answer (score 0):

With the new problem, the mean value theorem will tell you there is a root.  The question does not ask to find it.  If $x$ is huge and negative, the polynomial will be negative.  Just evaluate it at $x=-100$ and see that $p(-100)\lt 0$.  Then note $p(0)=10$ and you know there is a root in there somewhere.

Comment: ...im sorry I edited my question now its typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious algebraic answer, hinted to above. This one uses analytic geometry.

Recall that $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ is concave up iff $a>0$, and here $a=4$, so this is a parabola opening up, with a unique minimum point, which occurs at $$m = \frac{-b}{2a}=\frac{-1/7}{2\cdot 4} = -\frac{1}{56},$$ and
$$
p(m) = 10 + \sqrt{2} + \frac{4}{56} - \frac{1}{7 \cdot 56} > 9+\sqrt{2}>0,
$$
so the minimum point of $p$ is strictly above the $x$-axis, hence $p$ has no real roots.

Comment: @gt6989b.....im sorry I edited my question now its typing mistake